# Connecting to PubSub inside GAE application

Tags: go, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I've built an application in Go that connects to a Google PubSub to publish messages. It works perfectly in localhost (using pubsub emulator), but for some reason the connection hangs in GAE.

It hangs on this piece of code (removed unrelated code to improve readability)

```
import (
    "cloud.google.com/go/pubsub"
)

client, err := pubsub.NewClient(ctx, config.Project_ID)
if err != nil {
    return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "failed to create client")
}

topic, err := client.CreateTopic(ctx, id)  // HANGS HERE
```

This is the app.yaml

```
runtime: go114
instance_class: B1
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

Also, when the code is running (and hanged) it keeps outputting the following error message

```
internal.flushLog: Flush RPC: service bridge HTTP failed: Post "http://appengine.googleapis.internal:10001/rpc_http": dial tcp 169.254.169.253:10001: i/o timeout
```

It seems that something is dropping the packets sent to GCP internal API, but I don't know why or how to fix it. What I find even more weird is the fact that I have another app running almost the same code (and connecting successfully to pubsub). The only difference is that the app that is working is not the default service in GAE and the one that's failing is.

It seems like a network problem but unfortunately I haven't been able to find a solution online.

Below are the direct dependencies used by the app (extracted from go.mod)

```
cloud.google.com/go
cloud.google.com/go/storage
github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go
github.com/getsentry/sentry-go
github.com/go-ozzo/ozzo-validation
github.com/golang/gddo
github.com/google/uuid
github.com/gorilla/handlers
github.com/gorilla/mux
github.com/jackc/pgx
github.com/jinzhu/copier
github.com/joho/godotenv
github.com/lib/pq
github.com/ory/dockertest
github.com/pkg/errors
github.com/stretchr/testify
google.golang.org/appengine
google.golang.org/genproto
cloud.google.com/go/pubsub
github.com/satori/go.uuid
github.com/sirupsen/logrus
github.com/spf13/pflag
google.golang.org/grpc
```

Comment: Can you share your dependencies?

Comment: Is the application always hanging or after some time? I noticed that as per your app.yaml file you just have 1 B1 instance, maybe you could consider increasing the instance class or the number of instances. If your application is always hanging it could be a limitation of the Go Standard Runtime (since after taking a look at the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/writing-and-responding-to-pub-sub-messages) I see there isn't any information for Go).

Comment: Notice that there is a fairly [simple tutorial for App Engine Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/writing-and-responding-to-pub-sub-messages) from which you could base your application.

Answer (score 1):

Okay guys, I finally found out what has happened. Dumb mistake.

We were using the pubsub emulator to test the application locally and unfortunately we left the `PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8085` environment set in our GAE app. This means that the application was trying to connect with the emulator inside the GAE and not the real Pub/Sub. Since the emulator only exists locally, the application hangs on the TCP connection.

At least I can tell some thing to help other people that might have similar issues:

- Pub/Sub works with the GAE standard environment
- Pub/Sub works with Go 1.14 (you don't need to downgrade to 1.11)
- Check your environment variables :)